# Selecting Bottom of Modifier Stack in 3DS Max on Object Selection

Tags: 3ds-max

I'd like to be able to select an object and have the bottom modifier (e.g. Editable Poly) selected. The top of the stack gets selected, usually. In the image below, 'Turbosmooth' gets selected when I click on an object in the viewport.

[image]

When there's multiple objects in the scene, it's annoying having to go through the modifier window to manually select it each time, and I'm hoping there's a quicker way even if it was a script/macro available somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

After messing with MaxScript a bit, this is closest I can come up with, and it requires a custom hotkey, besides just selecting the object:

```
max modify mode -- Switch to Modify Tab
modPanel.setCurrentObject $.baseObject -- Select the base object in the modifier stack
```

You could then create a macroscript that looks like the below to put in your usermacros folder:

```
macroScript SelectBottomOfModifierStack
    category:"DragAndDrop"
    toolTip:""
(
    max modify mode -- Switch to Modify Tab
    modPanel.setCurrentObject $.baseObject -- Select the base object in the modifier stack
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Plugin which allows you to choose the modifier you want to select:

http://www.scriptspot.com/3ds-max/scripts/modifier-auto-select

Might be a bit overkill for you but could be useful for someone else.